# idiomatic phrases for the process of translating

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for idiomatic phrases to speak or write about the process of translating into/from a foreign language. I would like to find phrases that are a good fit for neutral style of communication.

> A customer requested **a translation** [made or done or carried out] **by** experts with a degree in software engineering.

or

> He **deals with** [does, carries out or makes] **translations** in the field of computer science.

or

> He was employed **to make translations** into French within the framework of the project of software customization.

or

> He is currently **providing a translation** into French within the scope of work for software customization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context, the verbs "make," "provide," "do," "produce," and "working on" could be used to describe the translation process in your examples (I've added [when necessary] and **'bolded'** the verb that I would use in each of your examples).  For variety, you could also just use the appropriate form of the verb "**translate**" with the word **"document(s)" (or "information")** in all of these (as I did in my original suggestions), but I wouldn't say that it would be better like that:

Sentence 1

A customer requested a translation [**MADE** or done or carried out] by experts with a degree in software engineering.

(original suggestion = "A customer requested that the document(s)/information be translated by experts with degreeS in software engineering.")

(I'd pluralize "degrees," but it could imply that they want each of the experts to hold multiple degrees, so maybe "... by degree-holding experts in the field of software engineering." would be the clearest.)

Sentence 2

He [deals with, **PROVIDES**, does, carries out or makes] translations in the field of computer science.

(original suggestion = "He translates documents/information in the field of computer science.")

Sentence 3

He was employed **TO MAKE** translations into French within the framework of the project of software customization.

(you could also use **PROVIDE** here, but you'd need to replace "translations into French" with "French translations": "He was employed **TO PROVIDE** French translations within the framework of the project of software customization." [in fact, I think making this replacement would be preferable, even if you use 'to make"])

(original suggestion = He was employed to translate [English (or whatever language) documents/information into French within the framework of the project of software customization. [the following might be clearer if it doesn't change the meaning]):

(= He was employed to translate [English (or whatever language) documents/information relating to software customization into French.)

Based on your comment clarifying what "within the framework ...etc" means, I'd suggest the following (and this would apply with whatever verb/noun combination that you choose to use):

"He was employed to translate documents/information into French as part of a/the software customization project."

Sentence 4

He is currently [providing, **PRODUCING** (or **WORKING ON**) a translation into French within the scope of work for software customization.

(here again, I'd replace "a translation into French" with "a French translation":

"He is currently **PRODUCING** (or **WORKING ON**) a French translation within the scope of work for software customization.")

(original suggestion = He is currently translating [English (or whatever language) documents/information into French within the scope of work for software customization. 
[like the one above, I'm not exactly sure what the last part of your sentence means and the following might be clearer if it doesn't change the meaning]): =

(=He is currently translating [English (or whatever language) documents/information relating to software customization into French.)

Again, based on your comment clarifying what "within the scope..etc" means, I'd suggest the following (and this would apply with whatever verb/noun combination that you choose to use):

"He is currently translating documents/information into French as part of a/the software customization project."

Comment: I see. Thank you. 'Within the framework of the project' or 'within the scope of work' were supposed to mean translation activity as part of an effort for [doing] something more global or great or time-consuming.